# SQL - remove trailing "/" in url with querystring

Tags: sql, sql-server, url, sql-update, trailing-slash

I have table with 2 columns where in one of them an url is stored.

Now I would need to update the table to remove all trailing slashes from the urls, including urls that have a query string.

Examples:

```
/page/sub/1/             =>    /page/sub/1
/page/sub/1/?page=1      =>    /page/sub/1?page=1
```

I've found how to do it for a trailing slash, but not when it's inside the url.

```
UPDATE TABLE 
SET MyUrl = LEFT(MyUrl, LEN(MyUrl) - 1) 
WHERE RIGHT(MyUrl, 1) = '/';
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do this? Can I use a regex of some kind?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention... SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE TABLE SET MyUrl = replace(MyUrl, '/?', '?') WHERE MyUrl like '%/?%';
```

[Working SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f44ba4/1)